# Isabelle/ZF infix definition issue

Tags: isabelle

I tried to define a definition like this:

```
theory intext
imports ZF.Int
begin

definition zmod :: "[i,i] ⇒ i" (infixl "$//" 69)
where 
  "a $// b == 0"
```

However, it shows error in "$//" the "a $// b == 0":

```
Inner syntax error⌂
Failed to parse prop
```

I tried to see if there is infix definition in ZF.Int, and I do find it, but the Isabelle shows error in the theory at the beginning:

```
Cannot update finished theory "ZF.Int"
```

May I know does anyone has experience in defining definition with infix operator in Isabelle/ZF could give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `/` is a special character in mixfix annotations, therefore you need to escape it using `'` as follows:

```
definition zmod :: "[i,i] ⇒ i" (infixl "$'/'/" 69)
where 
  "a $// b == 0"
```

For more information regarding mixfix annotations please refer to *The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual*, section 8.2.

Regarding the error message `Cannot update finished theory "ZF.Int"`, this means that `Int` is part of ZF and cannot be edited.